# Restoring a whole binary tree by it's postorder traversal results

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, postorder

can I restore a whole binary tree (count(vertices) = 2^n-1) only from an array that is sorted as if I did postorder traversal ?

The algorithm I suggest is very simple, just to make postorder traversal:

1. go left
2. go right
3. current_vertex = array[i++]; // initialized i = 0

that should do the job, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant as `post order array` of a `binary tree` can be converted to **more than one** binary trees which are not same out of which it is not possible to know which one was original.

Example-

Post order'd array `2 3 5` can be converted to many trees like-

```
2        // 3 is right child of 2 and 5 of 5
  3
    5
```

or

```
  5     //2 is left child and 3 is right child of 5
2   3
```

Comment: the first tree not possible, because it's given that it is a whole (full) binary tree, so there is only one like that.